# Splitting, trimming, converting to image and concatenating issues with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I am new to FFmpeg. I read some essential basics but cannot figure out why the following command does not work. The script is written in Windows in PowerShell.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner `
  -loop 1 -t 3 -i image.jpg `
  -i input.mp4 `
  -filter_complex "`
    [1:v] split=2 [v1][v2];
    [1:a] asplit=2 [a1][a2]; `
    [v1] trim=start=10:duration=10, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [ov1];`
    [a1] atrim=start=10:duration=10, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [oa1];`
    [v2] trim=start=40:duration=10, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [ov2];`
    [a2] atrim=start=40:duration=10, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [oa2];`
    [0][ov1][ov2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [v]; `
    [oa1][oa2] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [ca]; `
    [ca] adelay=3s|3s|3s|3s|3s|3s, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [a]; `
  "`
  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" `
  -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 `
  -c:a aac -b:a 128k `
  output.mp4
```

It only produces an image and FFMpeg reports the following warning:

> Non-monotonic DTS; previous: 1024, current: 0; changing to 1025. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

I figured out how to apply filters: `split` and `concat`. I knew I would need to label inputs and outputs in each part of the filter. I understood `-map` was required to indicate streams included in the output file.

I'm not sure if `-loop 1 -t 3 -i ...` is correct and the part with `PTS` has been copied from somewhere--I have a little understanding of what PTS is. Finally, the `adelay` would make audio stream synced with video streams after the image.

What I am trying to achieve here is:

- convert an image to a video
- clone the second input into two separate streams
- trim both such streams, and
- concatenate everything into one video/audio.

The image should take 3 secs, the remaining streams 10 secs each, so the whole video should be 23 secs long. It does not do that.

---

EDIT. More info about input/output files and FFMpeg itself. Please note all the above outputs were created by FFMpeg version by [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/). I am current working on FFMpeg by [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases)

The video is downloaded from [Download Sample Videos](https://sample-videos.com/) and the sample video itself is `.mp4` 10MB ([direct link](https://sample-videos.com/video321/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4)). Image is just a random JPEG cropped to size of 1280x720.

This is what `ffmpeg -version` prints:

```
ffmpeg version 2024-01-11-git-5e751dabc5-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      58. 36.101 / 58. 36.101
libavcodec     60. 37.100 / 60. 37.100
libavformat    60. 20.100 / 60. 20.100
libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
libavfilter     9. 17.100 /  9. 17.100
libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
```

The output of `ffprobe -hide_banner input.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:01:02.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1347 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 959 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

The output of `ffprobe -hide_banner output.mp4`

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 921 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 842 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : Lavc60.37.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Output of mediainfo on `input.jpg`

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\zbkoz\Desktop\demo-video\image.jpg
Format                                   : JPEG
File size                                : 519 KiB

Image
Format                                   : JPEG
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 519 KiB (100%)
ColorSpace_ICC                           : RGB
```

Comment: There is an extra `;` after `[a]`. Beside that, the issue is not reproducible. I tried to reproduce the issue by generating synthetic patterns: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 -update 1 -pix_fmt yuvj420p image.jpg` and `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=600 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 input.mp4` (it's always better to have the same input files as you have, for testing).

Comment: Command line: `ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loop 1 -t 3 -i image.jpg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]split=2[v1][v2];[1:a]asplit=2[a1][a2];[v1]trim=start=10:duration=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ov1];[a1]atrim=start=10:duration=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[oa1];[v2]trim=start=40:duration=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ov2];[a2]atrim=start=40:duration=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[oa2];[0][ov1][ov2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v];[oa1][oa2]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ca];[ca]adelay=3s|3s,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4`. It looks OK.

Comment: What is the video frame rate of `input.mp4`?

Comment: @Rotem Hi, thanks for the responses. The bitrate on `input.mp4` is `1347 kb/s`. I added all outputs from FFMpeg and Mediainfo. I hope you can use the same file apart from the image--I can't remember where I get it from. It's just a regular jpeg cropped to 1280x720 and exported to JPEG again in GIMP.

Comment: @Rotem I tried the line in your comment and have slightly different output then before: the image takes 3 secs, followed by a video but only for about 3 secs, not what I'd expect. Player is VLC 3.0.20 Vetinari. Everything is tested on Windows 10 64-bit. Cheers!

Comment: @Rotem I have installed a different build by [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) from [FFMpeg website](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) and everything works as I expect. On the other hand, the version of FFMpeg by [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) causes the problems I described. Shall I put this in answer?

Comment: What is the version number from gyan.dev? Make sure you are using a stable release like 6.1.1

Comment: It was `ffmpeg version 2024-01-11-git-5e751dabc5-full_build-www.gyan.dev`. Also, one more thing I am not sure about. `ffprobe input.mp4` reports audio stream as `5.1`, which I'd consider 5 channels. Does it mean I should repeat `3s` 5 times? Perhaps I have wrong number of `3s`, that is 6.

Comment: Version `2024-01-11-git-5e751dabc5` is not a "stable release". `5.1` layout applies 6 audio channels. I think you can use the syntax: `adelay=3s:all=1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but am not entirely sure if this qualifies for an answer.

Essentially, the script seems to work without issues on a build by [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases). I decided to install the other version from [Download FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) as I was told in comments the problem could not be reproduced.

I can confirm that the script still does not work on FFMpeg [Windows builds from gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/).